# Regex - C# Replace SQL wild card characters

Tags: c#, regex, t-sql, replace, wildcard

I have some input that works with EF Core's `EF.Function.Like`.

So I may receive input like this `%some_text%`, where the wild card characters are `%` and `_`

I need to take this and give it to another filtering mechanism that isn't SQL, where there is only the `*` wildcard.

So the above would become `*some*text*`.

However, SQL can escape its wildcard characters like so. `%some[_]te_t[%]`, which should convert to `*some_te*t%`

How can this replace be done with Regex using C#?

Comment: I have added an answer which might help, but can you add to the question what you have tried? I think I read the question, and seeing all the brackets and the asterix I assumed there was a pattern there :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use 2 capturing groups and check for example if group 2 has a value. If not, return the value of group 1 which captures the value between the square brackets.

As the brackets themselves are matched, they are not part of the replacement.

```
\[([%_])\]|([%_])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/02fe1E/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/KfNhep)

Example code

```
string[] strings = { 
    "%some_text%",
    "%some[_]te_t[%]"
    };

foreach (String s in strings) {
    var result = Regex.Replace(
        s, 
        @"\[([%_])\]|([%_])", match =>
        match.Groups[2].Success ? "*" : match.Groups[1].Value
    );
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Output

```
*some*text*
*some_te*t%
```